# number automatically of cluster hierchical clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have a question related to hierchical clustering.

My data set contains 10.000 objects. When I proceed to a clustering based on a hierchical clustering I obtain in final 30 clusters.
I have used average link to do so.
The issue is that I don't undrestand how the final number of clusters is determened automatically by the algorithm?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hierarchical clustering does not determine the number of clusters.

Whatever tool you are using, may however implement a *default value* how to cut the HAC dendrogram into partitions. But this is very much implementation specific.

There are different logics how to cut the dendrogram. For example, if you don't execute the last 29 merges, then you get 30 clusters. Or you stop meringue at a distance threshold x (but of course the value is very much data dependant). Or the HDBSCAN* approach, or ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which software you have used for clustering, and what dataset. In any case, in Hierarchical Clustering *you* either decide how many clusters you want; or, alternatively, what value of an error metric or distance metric to accept,  and this gives you the clusters (and, of course, the number of clusters).

In R you can use the built-in `cutree()` function to do so. it takes three arguments:

```
     cutree(tree, k = NULL, h = NULL)

Arguments:

    tree: a tree as produced by ‘hclust’. ‘cutree()’ only expects a
          list with components ‘merge’, ‘height’, and ‘labels’, of
          appropriate content each.

       k: an integer scalar or vector with the desired number of groups

       h: numeric scalar or vector with heights where the tree should
          be cut.
```

In other words,
`tree` is your clustered data, `k` is the number of clusters you want, and `h` is the maximum error metric (converted to a humanreadable scale). You get h by trial and error , from looking at a plot.
You specify either k or h.

This does not necessarily mean that the algorithm always proposes clusters that are useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the answer in the matlab codes.
In their comments at the beggining they defined it:

DENDROGRAM(Z,P) generates a dendrogram with no more than P leaf nodes,
by collapsing lower branches of the tree.  To display the complete tree, set P = 0. The Default value of P is 30.

Thank you